# C++17 : Are 'Selection Statements with Initializer' broken?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17

Let's say I start with;

```
...
auto b = foo(a);
if (!a && (b < c))
{
    bar(b);
}
...
```

And I notice I can optimize it for C++17 using the nice new 'selection statements with initializer' to become;

```
...
if (!a && (auto b = foo(a); (b < c)))
{
    bar(b);
}
...
```

then, to my dismay, ***it doesn't compile***, under GCC 7.2

Now this IS in the spirit of the point of the change to C++17, neater **AND** would have neatly skipped the creation of the local variable if the first test, '!a' fails, which would be nice and neatly efficient.

However, if I change it to;

```
...
if (!a)
{
    if (auto b = foo(a); (b < c))
    {
        bar(b);
    }
}
...
```

then it works... BUT what's the point since this is simply;

```
...
if (!a)
{
    auto b = foo(a); 
    if (b < c)
    {
        bar(b);
    }
}
...
```

which seems to spoil the whole point of having the 'statement selection with initializer' in the first place.

**Q. So is this feature of C++17 broken or useless cosmetic fluff if it doesn't allow parts of conditions to have this feature and demands the ENTIRE 'if' carries it?**

Comment: **A: No**.  Not sure what else to say.

Comment: So it was always designed to just be cosmetic fluff? Thanks. I thought as much.

Comment: @DavidHParry: A feature is not just "cosmetic fluff" just because it doesn't do what *you* want it to do. The feature is not "arbitrary variable declarations in the middle of an expression".

Comment: This doesn't look like a question but like a rant about a particular C++ feature the OP cannot use under very specific circumstances.

Comment: @DavidHParry: "*So is this feature of C++17 broken or useless cosmetic fluff if it doesn't allow parts of conditions to have this feature and demands the ENTIRE 'if' carries it?*" Initializers in `if` statements are not intended to do any of that. It is a simple tool for a simple purpose. It is not meant to generalize variable declarations in expressions, nor is it intended to scope a variable declaration to an arbitrary part of an expression. It exists to prevent scope leak for a variable used in conditions and their blocks.

Comment: @davidh Your question was a compound one with a conditional in it (long clause IF some claim?).  I answered it as written (A if B? means "is B->A true?") ; your interpretation of my answer indicates you failed to write the question you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 4):

The initializer needs to come before the boolean expression. For example, try this:

```
if (auto b = foo(a); (!a && (b < c))) {
    bar(b);
}
```

If you don't want `foo(a)` to be called based on the boolean condition, you can always try something like this:

```
if (int b; (!a && ((b = foo(a)) < c))) {
    bar(b);
}
```

Clearly, `foo(a)` will not be called if `a` is true.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I change it to;
>
> ```
> ...
> if (!a)
> {
>     if (auto b = foo(a); (b < c))
>     {
>         bar(b);
>     }
> }
> ...
> ```
>
> then it works... BUT what's the point since this is simply;
>
> ```
> ...
> if (!a)
> {
>     auto b = foo(a); 
>     if (b < c)
>     {
>         bar(b);
>     }
> }
> ...
> ```

Nope. In the first snippet the scope of `b` is limited to the inner `if` statement. In the second snippet, the  scope of `b` spans the outer `if` statement.

Comment: So that's its only purpose? Scope limitation that makes no difference in real-world circumstances unless someone is foolish enough to always use the same variable names for temp variables? I think the developers missed a trick.

Comment: @DavidHParry: "*Scope limitation that makes no difference in real-world circumstances*" Spoken like a person who has never used RAII.